# SHA256CryptoServiceProvider not FIPS compliant?

Tags: c#, encryption

I am looking for a SHA256 implementation in C# that is FIPS compliant. It turns out that SHA1CryptoServiceProvider works. But why does SHA256CryptoServiceProvider trip the

> ```
> {"This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms."}
> ```

error? Seems like it should just work.

```
var sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create();   // not FIPS
```

In this case I am using .NET 4.5, but the same thing happens in 3.5 and 4.0. I thought SHA256CryptoServiceProvider was the FIPS-compliant alternative to SHA256Managed. SHA256Cng throws the same error.

**Update.** I think I needed to make a "new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider" instead of using Create()

Comment: Did that update solve your issue? As far as I can see, there is no `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create()` method? Or do you have the same issue, but no compilation issues anymore?

Comment: That method definitely exists. I think everything is working now.

Comment: OK, never imagined that such a thing could make a difference. Could you convert your update to an answer (and accept it after a while)? Seems interesting enough for other visitors.

Comment: Yes. Convert your update to an answer.

Answer (score 6):

As the original poster suggested in the update, the solution is to actually create a new instance of the SHA256CryptoServiceProvider (or 512).  Calling Create will not work:

```
var csp = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hashedBytes = csp.ComputeHash(......);
String hashedText = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create()`, but there is a [`SHA256.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256.create?view=netframework-4.8) :

> On the .NET Framework, this method creates an instance of the SHA256Managed class if FIPS mode is not active; if FIPS mode is active, it creates an instance of the SHA256Cng class.

There is one caveat, however (which maybe was the original problem):

> **On .NET 4.6.1 and earlier, with FIPS enabled, this picked `SHA256Managed`, which is not FIPS-compliant.**

If you want to target .NET <= 4.6.1, you can use something along the lines of:

```
public static SHA256 CreateSHA256()
{
    try
    {
        return SHA256.Create();
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException)
    {
        return SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
    }
}
```