# Why does the Create() method of SHA-1 behave differently than that of SHA-256?

Tags: c#, .net, security, hash, cryptography

Why does the `Create()` method of the `Cng`-Type of SHA **1** return a `CryptoServiceProvider`, while that of SHA **256** returns a `Managed`?

<sub>(**In other words**: Why does SHA**1**Cng.Create() return a `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider`, while SHA**256**Cng.Create() returns a `SHA256Managed`?)</sub>

(If you can explain why `SHA256Cng.Create()` was implemented to create a `SHA256Managed` instead of a `SHA256Cng`, I'd be interesting in that too. Currently, to create a `SHA256Cng` we need to use `SHA256.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng")`.)

Comment: We can't look into the minds of .net framework implementors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. True. But perhaps there's a reason that's obvious for someone with more knowledge than mine.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Generally I just ask, but I'm not sure that works with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

May be because of framework version. SHA256Cng is newer than SHA256Managed. Some details are here:
[Difference between SHA256CryptoServiceProvider and SHA256Managed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554882/difference-between-sha256cryptoserviceprovider-and-sha256managed)

SHA256Cng has FIPS rules. So you cannot use this class for some encryption/signing class. SHA256Managed hasn't got limitiations.
By default FIPS are disabled on OS. If change your OS setting may be default class change:
http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/12/How-to-enable-FIPS-Compliant-algorithms.html

Comment: "SHA256Managed is newer than SHA256Cng" not sure why you say that. [SHA256Managed has been in the framework since .NET 1.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed(v=vs.71).aspx). SHA256Cng appeared in .NET 3.5.

Comment: You are right, SHA256Cng is newer. I must have read incorrect something.