# What is the difference between the ASP.NET Core 3.1 SHA512 and SHA256Managed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am currently using `SHA256Managed` in `ASP.NET Core 3.1` and to be more secure, I would like to use the `Hash512`.

The `Managed` postfix suggests that one is managed code where the other is not.

Can someone please explain any concerns that one would need to consider when using unmanaged vs managed? Does the unmanaged required any special deployment e.g. in a Docker container / or operating system requirements.

```
    private string Hash512(string str) {
        var message = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        var hash = SHA512.Create();

        var hashValue = hash.ComputeHash(message);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(hashValue);
    }

    public string Hash256(string str)
    {
        var message = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        var hash = new SHA256Managed();

        var hashValue = hash.ComputeHash(message);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(hashValue);
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? Compare `SHA512` and `SHA256Managed`?

Comment: Is your question actually as to the difference of, for example, `SHA256` and `SHA256Managed`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated my question, and hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>(I originally marked this as a duplicate of [Difference between SHA256CryptoServiceProvider and SHA256Managed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554882/difference-between-sha256cryptoserviceprovider-and-sha256managed) - however this question is specifically in the context of ASP.NET Core 3.x which isn't the same as the linked question (.NET Framework on Windows).)</sup>

You're conflating two different things:

- `SHA256` represents the 256-bit flavor of the SHA-2 cryptographic hashing function, while, `SHA256Managed`, `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider` and `SHA256Cng` are its implementations.
- `SHA512` represents the 512-bit flavor of the SHA-2 cryptographic hashing function, while, `SHA512Managed`, `SHA512CryptoServiceProvider` and `SHA512Cng` are its implementations.

[The differences between the 256-bit and 512-bit versions of SHA-2 are documented on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2). Note that .NET does not support the 224-bit version, but does support the 256, 384 and 512-bit versions.

Regarding the differences between `SHA{bits}` (the interface) and `SHA{bits}Managed`, `SHA{bits}CryptoServiceProvider` and `SHA{bits}Cng`:

- The .NET Framework and .NET Core support multiple different implementations of the same hashing algorithms, this can be because some implementations may be hardware accelerated, provided by the operating system, or implemented entirely in C#/Managed-code.
- `SHA256` is an abstract base class that defines the interface of all implementations of the SHA-2 (256-bit) hashing function. Ditto `SHA512` for the SHA-2 (512-bit) function.
- `SHA256Managed` (and `SHA512Managed`) are 100% C#/Managed-code implementations that do run slowly compared to native or OS-provided implementations. This is the only implementation provided that's built-in to .NET Core.
- `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider` and `SHA256Cng` are OS-provided implementations that may be used for faster performance or for FIPS compliance (as `SHA256Managed` is not FIPS compliant). If you don't know if you need to worry about FIPS compliance then you probably don't need to worry about it (i.e. unless you're working for the US federal government or your company's legal team has informed you of your project's regulatory compliance requirements).

  - Additionally, `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider` and `SHA256Cng` are not built-in to .NET Core, only .NET Framework.
- The `SHA256.Create()` method is a factory method that is meant to return the "best" implementation for the current platform - in .NET Core it always returns an instance of `SHA256Managed`.

Comment: Dear Dai, if I am not reading incorrectly, .Net Core repository on GitHub says otherwise about SAH256Managed and SHA512Managed classes. SHA512Managed class has a fully managed implementation for .Net Framework, yes, but for [.Net Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/SHA512Managed.cs), it seems like it is always linking to the native implementation, which on windows is bcrypt

Comment: Thanks for sharing Dai, explained very well.

Comment: @OguzOzgul `bcrypt` has nothing to do with SHA at all. bcrypt is not a part of the .NET Framework or .NET Core either - where are you seeing that? As for `SHA512Managed` not being fully-managed - it does seem that things are changing with the upcoming ".NET 5" release. I maintain the information in my answer is correct as far as .NET Core 3.0 and .NET Framework 4.8 are concerned.

Comment: In the link in my comment (.Net Core source code, SHA512Managed.cs). `-> HashProviderDispenser -> HashProviderCng -> Interop.BCrypt.BCryptCreateHash()`

Comment: @OguzOzgul Interesting. I don't have an explanation for that, sorry. It might be an attempt to be backwards-compatible?