# Should SHA1CryptoServiceProvider and SHA256Managed return same value

Tags: c#, sha256

I've seen questions stating the same hash is generated, but with the following code:

```
    var password = "TestPassword";

    using (var hash = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        Console.WriteLine( Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes) );
    }
    using (var managed = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        var hashBytes = managed.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes));
    }
```

The output is:

```
YlBiWyJt9ihwriOvjT+sB2DXFYg=
e8+diSmPG/rhb6Au1rYZCP0vqN5F3Y4hU6PEcwB2Uyg=
```

Am I not using the crypto libraries correctly?

Comment: SHA-1 and SHA-256 (a variant of SHA-2) are different hash functions.

Comment: Grr...missed that difference.  Good eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHA1 and SHA256 are two different hash functions. (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms)